# Laravel cannot find PDF files in Storage

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, routes, storage

I'm struggling with **Laravel 5.7** issue. When I'm trying to open in my app PDF file from my storage/public it shows 404 error. I've already linked storage to public by `php artisan storage:link`. The problem occurs on my hosting  web server (I guess it's powered by LiteSpeed). On my local server everything works by calling source from `assets($path)` [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4rPn.png), but on my VPS server I had to make source to file static [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbRXa.png). On my web server I can't use any of these, because it calls 404. The funny thing is I've got images in the same folder also, and it works properly linked by `assets($path)` but PDF files show 404 error. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Url should be absolute

```
<a href="/storage/pdf/{{ $pdf->url }}">Skan {{ $pdf->ID }}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{ config('app.url') }}/storage/pdf/{{ $pdf->url }}">Skan {{ $pdf->ID }}</a>
```